# X-axis changes Excel plot output

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have the following Excel file:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33532467/GDV_Prognose_Leben.xlsx

The green hatched area is not shown properly. I would expect:

[image]

The horizontal axis seems to change the plot output.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

To get the results you want, you'll need to add one helper row.

1. Add an additional row to your data (I called it Projection-Charted).
2. For the values, subtract Vorab-Projektion Worst Case from Vorab Projektion (=B6-B5 in your workbook).
3. Add this row as a data series in your chart, replacing your original Vorab Projektion series.

Your results should look like this:

[image: Modified Area Chart]

Also, I'd recommend converting your ** values in 2005 to =NA() (which returns #N/A in Excel, which it can properly handle in the chart (not plotting it).